# Linker command failed with exit code 1 Facebook SDK

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, linker-errors

The errors started to occur as follows after adding the Facebook SDK to my project ("FacebookSDK.framework")

ld: 76 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkTarget._URL in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkTarget._appStoreId in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkTarget._appName in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFAppLinkTarget in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFAppLinkTarget in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTaskCompletionSource._task in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTaskCompletionSource.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTaskCompletionSource.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTaskCompletionSource.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTaskCompletionSource.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTaskCompletionSource.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTaskCompletionSource.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._includeStatusBarInSize in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._labelView in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._closeButton in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._insideTapGestureRecognizer in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._closed in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._textColor in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._refererAppLink in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._delegate in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._viewToMoveWithNavController in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController._attachedToNavController in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController._view in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController._delegate in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFWebViewAppLinkResolverWebViewDelegate._didFinishLoad in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFWebViewAppLinkResolverWebViewDelegate._didFailLoadWithError in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFWebViewAppLinkResolverWebViewDelegate._hasLoaded in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFWebViewAppLinkResolverWebViewDelegate in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFWebViewAppLinkResolverWebViewDelegate in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFWebViewAppLinkResolver in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFWebViewAppLinkResolver in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
duplicate symbol _warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTask.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTask._result in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTask.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTask._error in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTask.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTask._exception in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTask.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTask._cancelled in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTask.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTask._completed in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTask.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTask._lock in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTask.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTask._condition in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTask.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTask._callbacks in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTask.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTask in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTask.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFTask in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTask.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTask.o)
duplicate symbol _kBFMultipleErrorsError in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(Bolts.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Bolts.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Bolts in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(Bolts.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Bolts.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Bolts in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(Bolts.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Bolts.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLink._sourceURL in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLink._targets in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLink._webURL in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkDataParameterName in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkTargetKeyName in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkUserAgentKeyName in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkExtrasKeyName in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkRefererAppLink in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkRefererAppName in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkRefererUrl in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkVersionKeyName in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _BFAppLinkVersion in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFAppLink in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFAppLink in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFExecutor._block in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFExecutor.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFExecutor.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExecutor in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFExecutor.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFExecutor.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFExecutor in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFExecutor.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFExecutor.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFURL._inputURL in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFURL.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFURL.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFURL._targetURL in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFURL.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFURL.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFURL._inputQueryParameters in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFURL.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFURL.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFURL._targetQueryParameters in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFURL.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFURL.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFURL._appLinkData in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFURL.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFURL.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFURL._appLinkExtras in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFURL.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFURL.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFURL._appLinkReferer in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFURL.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFURL.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFURL in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFURL.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFURL.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFURL in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFURL.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFURL.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkNavigation._extras in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkNavigation._appLinkData in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkNavigation._appLink in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFAppLinkNavigation in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFAppLinkNavigation in:
    /Users/sorewarding/Downloads/aws-ios-sdk-2.0.3/third-party/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
    /Users/sorewarding/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
ld: 76 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This could be a possible duplicate (as I have searched everywhere), but I still could not solve it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks, but I really approciate if you can suggest me a solution within the thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS and Facebook SDK together, you should not import `Bolts.framework` in your project. If you remove it, it should compile.

Comment: @Yosuke I fixed this, but had to upgrade to the new facebook sdk. I think how I fixed this was removing some components of Bolt from the Facebook SDK. If I remove the Bolts framework from the aws sdk i get dependency errors for aws files. what should i do?

Comment: This worked for me as well with the newest Facebook SDK: facebook-ios-sdk-3.21.1

Comment: In my case, also Bolts was added twice. I removed it from the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries"  and got past this error, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Newer SDK of FB named "FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910.zip"
Then due to app thinning It might not work in Xcode prior to v7.

So either try it in latest XCODE v7

or

Try to use Older one "[FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150813.zip](https://developers.facebook.com/resources/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150813.zip)"